# BigQuery: Converting Legacy SQL Query to Standard SQL

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am converting legal SQL Query to Standard SQL Query in Bigquery to calculate google analytics bounce rate. But on Converting the query there is some difference in the output result.

Legacy SQL Query

```
SELECT session_bounceRate,

  t1.source as source,t1.medium as medium,

  total_session

FROM (
  SELECT
    IFNULL(t1.session_bounceSessionCount, 0) / t2.session_sessionId_distinct_count AS session_bounceRate,
    t1.source,t1.medium,
    t2.total_session_distinct_count AS total_session
  FROM (
    SELECT
      INTEGER(session_bounceSession_distinct_count) AS session_bounceSessionCount,
    source,
        medium
    FROM (
      SELECT
        COUNT(DISTINCT session_sessionId, 10000000) AS session_bounceSession_distinct_count,    --Changes done (Count(x) in legacy sql stands for approx ,
      source,                                                                                   --,so replaced it with APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT to get approx count
        medium from (
        SELECT
          SUM(IF(session_hitsType = 'event'
              AND session_isInteraction_first = 1, 1, 0)) AS session_isEventInteraction_sum,
          session_sessionId AS session_sessionId,
          SUM(session_pageViews_sum) AS session_pageViews_sum_sum,
           source,
           medium
        FROM (
          SELECT
            hits.type AS session_hitsType,
            sessionId AS session_sessionId,
            SUM(totals.pageviews) AS session_pageViews_sum,
            FIRST(hits.isInteraction) AS session_isInteraction_first,
            trafficSource.source AS source,
            trafficSource.medium AS medium,

          FROM
            TABLE_DATE_RANGE([[test:test.session_streaming_], TIMESTAMP('2018-04-01'), TIMESTAMP('2018-04-30')) AS session_streaming
          GROUP BY
            source,
            medium,
            session_hitsType,
            session_sessionId )
        GROUP BY
          source,
          medium,
          session_sessionId )
      WHERE
        (session_isEventInteraction_sum = 0
          AND session_pageViews_sum_sum = 1)
      GROUP BY
        source,
        medium ) ) AS t1
  JOIN EACH ( 
    SELECT
      COUNT(DISTINCT sessionId, 10000000) AS session_sessionId_distinct_count,
      trafficSource.source AS source,
      trafficSource.medium AS medium,
      COUNT(DISTINCT sessionId, 10000000) AS total_session_distinct_count

    FROM
      TABLE_DATE_RANGE([test:Test.session_streaming_], TIMESTAMP('2018-04-01'), TIMESTAMP('2018-04-30')) AS session_streaming
    GROUP BY
      source,
       medium ) AS t2
  ON
    t1.source = t2.source  
    and t1.medium=t2.medium)
where t1.medium='zadv_display'
ORDER BY
  total_session DESC
```

Standard SQL Query

```
SELECT
  IFNULL(t1.session_bounceSessionCount, 0) / t2.session_sessionId_distinct_count AS session_bounceRate,
  t1.source,
  t1.medium,
      t2.total_session_distinct_count AS total_session
FROM (
  SELECT
    CAST(session_bounceSession_distinct_count AS INT64) AS session_bounceSessionCount,
    source,
    medium

  FROM (
    SELECT
      APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(DISTINCT session_sessionId) AS session_bounceSession_distinct_count,
      source,
      medium

    FROM (
      SELECT
        SUM(IF(session_hitsType = 'event'
            AND session_isInteraction_first = 1, 1, 0)) AS session_isEventInteraction_sum,
        session_sessionId AS session_sessionId,
        SUM(session_pageViews_sum) AS session_pageViews_sum_sum,
        source,
        medium

      FROM (
        SELECT
          session_hitsType,
          session_sessionId,

          source,
          medium,
          CASE
            WHEN session_isInteraction_first = TRUE THEN 1
            ELSE 0
          END AS session_isInteraction_first,
          SUM(session_pageViews_sum) AS session_pageViews_sum
        FROM (
          SELECT
            hits.Type AS session_hitsType,
            sessionId AS session_sessionId,

            trafficSource.source AS source,
            trafficSource.medium AS medium,
            totals.pageviews AS session_pageViews_sum,
            FIRST_VALUE(hits.isInteraction) OVER(PARTITION BY sessionId ORDER BY TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(hits.Time)) AS session_isInteraction_first
          FROM
            `test.Test.session_streaming_*`,
            unNEST(hits) hits
          WHERE
            _table_suffix BETWEEN '20180401'
            AND '20180430' )
        GROUP BY
          session_hitsType,
          session_sessionId,

          source,
          medium,
          session_isInteraction_first )
      GROUP BY
        source,
        medium,
        session_sessionId)
    WHERE
      (session_isEventInteraction_sum = 0
        AND session_pageViews_sum_sum = 1)
    GROUP BY
      source,
      medium)) AS t1
JOIN (
  SELECT
    APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(DISTINCT sessionId) AS session_sessionId_distinct_count,
    trafficSource.source AS source,
    trafficSource.medium AS medium,
    APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(DISTINCT sessionId) AS total_session_distinct_count

  FROM
    `test.Test.session_streaming_*`
  WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN '20180401' AND '20180430'
  GROUP BY
    source,
    medium
    ) AS t2
ON
  t1.source = t2.source
       AND t1.medium=t2.medium
  where t1.medium='zadv_display'
  order by total_session desc
```

We have replace First function in value with First_value in standard sql that is the noticeable change made in the query.

Could Someone guide me is there some issue on conversion as standard sql query query output should match with legacy output?

Comment: Could you provide some output example with dummy data? since the second query will order TIMESTAMP_SECONDS, I guess session_isInteraction_first may be altered with the ordering and it will affect the calculation based on this attribute. Or your dataset is ordered already by TIMESTAMP_SECONDS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure you really need all those nested queries. 
But you should make use of sub-queries on arrays - a lot. E.g. the first event interaction information in a session goes like this:

```
SELECT
  date,
  visitStartTime,
  (SELECT isInteraction FROM t.hits WHERE type='EVENT' ORDER BY hitNumber ASC LIMIT 1) AS isInteraction
FROM
  `project.dataset.ga_sessions_20180624` AS t
LIMIT
  1000
```

So simply treat (struct-)arrays like smaller tables within a bigger table.
If you only have aggregations to session level, you shouldn't flatten the table at all.
Here's also a document explaining the migration to standard sql: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql